# File Provider Issue on Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I am using File provider for installing downloaded APK using Google Package installer in Android TV But always stuck on Package Parsing Error.

The same code base is working fine on android Mobile phone OS but not on Android TV. To note, Mine is a system application and have all the required permissions like REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but still no luck.

Can any folk please help me if this is a known bug on Android TV or there is something special need my attention.

Checklist:
1. Provider cross-checked with authority to grantURIPermissions

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
<files-path
    name="data"
    path="."/>
<cache-path
    name="cache"
    path="." />
<external-path name="external_download" path="Download"/>
<external-files-path name="Download" path="Download/" />
```

```
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this@MainActivity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider", file)
                        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true)
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
                        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                        val resInfoList = context?.packageManager?.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
                        resInfoList?.let {
                            for (res in resInfoList) {
                                val packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName
                                context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri,  Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                                context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri,  Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                                context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri,  Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
                            }
                        }

                        startActivity(intent)

internal fun getDownloadFileLoc(context: Context): String {
    val fileDir = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/download" 
    val fileName = context.getString(R.string.apk_name)
    return "$fileDir/$fileName"
}
```

I get a warning that permission denial for provider. Please tell me if I have to provide some specific information.

Comment: Are you trying to update the existing system app or are you trying to push your application as a system app?
Can you also post the error thrown by the provider?

Comment: I am already a system app, you can say prebuilt with firmware and I am trying to update itself. I am getting the same SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider package_name that is not exported from uid 1000